# Assigning a concrete Task<TImplementation> to a variable of type Task<TInterface>

Tags: c#, inheritance, interface, casting, task-parallel-library

Consider a class `Foo` which wholly implements `IFoo`.
Concurrently, consider a task `Task<IFoo>`.

Why is it that when the following is called, a compilation error is thrown;

```
Task<IFoo> task = Task.Factory.StartNew(() => new Foo());
```

The compiler states that it cannot convert from source type `Task<Foo>` to `Task<IFoo>`. While this makes sense because they are essentially two differing types, would it not fall under the same premise as `IList<IFoo> list = new List<IFoo>{new Foo(/* construct */)};`, or other similar assignments?

At the moment I am forcing a cast to the interface, but this feels unneccesary.

Comment: Your counter-example isn't counter. List<Foo> cannot be assigned to IList<IFoo>, either.

Comment: Huh, you're right. I guess this falls under the same blanket then.

Comment: I usually return concrete from a mixture of Portland Cement ad water. Perhaps you could edit your title to be more descriptive.

Comment: Daniel, I edited your title to be a bit more precise, in line with the suggestion from @PieterGeerkens.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

That is because this statement `Task.Factory.StartNew(() => new Foo());` returns an instance of type `Task<Foo>`.

And given that the `Task<>` class is a concrete class, it cannot be covariant, unless it were implementing a covariant interface (i.e. `ITask<out T>`).

Note that there is a uservoice topic to do just that: ["Make Task implement covariant interface ITask"](https://visualstudio.uservoice.com/forums/121579-visual-studio/suggestions/5754247-make-task-t-implement-covariant-interface-itask-o).

Also note the following possible explanation on why it is the way is it now, ["Lack of Covariance in the Task Class"](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/2a350bb3-b1cc-48a1-8684-8e67cf17bf55/lack-of-covariance-in-the-task-class?forum=async):

> Framework guidelines are:
>
> - If your framework already includes an interface for other reasons, then by all means make it co+contravariant.
> - But don't introduce an interface solely for the purposes of enabling co+contravariance.
>
> The justification is that the advantage of covariance is outweighed by the disadvantage of clutter (i.e. everyone would have to make a decision about whether to use `Task<T>` or `ITask<T>` in every single place in their code).

For now you will have to do:

```
Task<IFoo> task = Task.Factory.StartNew<IFoo>(() => new Foo());
```

Comment: Thanks, for this. What I was really after what a why rather than a how, and this hit the nail on the head.

Comment: @DanielPark If you think this sufficiently addressed your question, you may want to accept it as the answer, so that your question can be removed from the "unanswered questions" list.

Answer (score 0):

You can use generic version

```
Task<IFoo> task = Task.Run<IFoo>(() => new Foo());
```